# Storage pictures aren't visible on deployed website. Storage is linked and visible on public

Tags: laravel, image, deployment, storage

On my deployed Laravel project, storage images aren't visible. I have linked storage to public with `php artisan storage:link`. I can see the linked folder in my `public` folder (content of `public` is `css`,  `favicon.ico`, `fonts`, `images`, `index.php`, `js`, `revolution`, `robots.txt`, `storage`, and `vendor`).

I don't have any problem on local. I use `o2switch` and `cPanel`.

My html code is:

```html
<img src="https://mywebsite/storage/1/6.webp" name="6.webp" class="w-100">
```

I can't see a picture.

But if I use this code:

```html
<img src="https://mywebsite/images/logo-dark.png" name="6.webp" class="w-100">
```

I can see a picture.

Comment: if you run `ls -la` inside `public`, do you correctly see that `storage` points to the right folder? Which one is it pointing to?

Comment: Can you confirm the image stored from path `public/storage/1/6.webp`?

Comment: @matiaslauriti
when I run ls -la in my public folder I see fine

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 yucn3608 yucn3608 44 Apr 26 22:45 storage -> /home/yucn3608/auto4sale/storage//app/public`

Strangely there is a double /. 
Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Charlie
the result of `pwd` is `/home/yucn3608/auto4sale/public/storage/1` and I have `6.webp` in this folder.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have solved the problem with dubble `/`. That doesn't solve the problem with images

Comment: What is the content of the storage app public folder?